# How do I get a RoseWill rk-8100 keyboard working?

Tags: keyboard

I am using this http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16823201048
keyboard , it works fine in windows and other version of linux like puppy linux , but when ever I try using it on ubuntu or any ubuntu based distro , the lights on the keyboard work but none of the keys do .  I have pluged in other keyboards and they work ,  so I don't know what to think.

Comment: I have the same issue (with the exact same keyboard), I am currently having to use a different one. Did anyone ever find a fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this keyboard is unsupported. My brother just got the same keyboard and I have done some research on Rosewill's website. Not only are there no drivers but I can't seem to get Ubuntu to recognize it after several attempts.

Answer (score 0):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2134610

> There's not much about getting this keyboard working in Linux on the
>   web but after much searching and trial and error this is what works
>
> - Ubuntu 13.04 (dev) using 3.8.0-17-generic
> - Kanotix using kernel 3.8.2-2-486....
>
> Not working
>
> - Ubuntu 12.04 using kernel 3.2.0
> - Ubuntu 12.10 using kernel 3.5.0
>
> In short the older kernels do not support the Rosewill RIKB-11003
>   keyboard so if your new to GNU/Linux Ubuntu LinuxMint I would
>   recommend waiting a bit and upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04 when it comes
>   out later this month.

I found this solution also helped my RK-8100

There's plenty of guides for installing 3.8.5, but this is the one i used:
http://www.upubuntu.com/2013/03/install-linux-kernel-385-in-ubuntu.html

```
cd /tmp 
wget http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47950494/upubuntu.com/kernel-3.8.5 -O kernel-3.8.5 
chmod +x kernel-3.8.5 
sudo sh kernel-3.8.5 
sudo reboot
```

You can also find the packages here:
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Comment: FWIW: it's generally a bad idea to download scripts and then run them. Please read the script before running it. Or better yet, read it and run the commands inside yourself.

Comment: After 4 years, I'm back on this thread trying to figure out why my linux kernel is crashing with this keyboard. If you're trying to decide if you should buy this keyboard for a linux computer, my advice is stay away.